# Стек - задача на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, циклы, стек

Вообще не понимаю, как решать данную задачу, прошу побольше объяснений к коду.

---

Реализуйте класс `StackMaxEffective`, поддерживающий операцию определения максимума среди элементов в стеке. Сложность операции должна быть O(1). Для пустого стека операция должна возвращать `None`. При этом `push(x)` и `pop()` также должны выполняться за константное время.

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке записано одно число — количество команд, оно не превосходит 100000. Далее идут команды по одной в строке. Команды могут быть следующих видов:

- `push(x)` — добавить число x в стек;
- `pop()` — удалить число с вершины стека;
- `get_max()` — напечатать максимальное число в стеке;

Если стек пуст, при вызове команды `get_max` нужно напечатать `«None»`, для команды `pop` — `«error»`.

**Формат вывода**

Для каждой команды `get_max()` напечатайте результат её выполнения. Если стек пустой, для команды `get_max()` напечатайте `«None»`. Если происходит удаление из пустого стека — напечатайте `«error»`.

**Пример 1:**

Ввод:

```
10
pop
pop
push 4
push -5
push 7
pop
pop
get_max
pop
get_max
```

Вывод:

```
error
error
4
None
```

**Пример 2:**

Ввод:

```
10
get_max
push -6
pop
pop
get_max
push 2
get_max
pop
push -2
push -6
```

Вывод:

```
None
error
None
2
```

*Python 3.7.3 | Ограничение времени - 1,5 секунды | Ограничение памяти - 64Mb*

Мой код:

```
class StackMax:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.max_items = []

    def push(self, item):

        if bool(self.items) and bool(self.max_items):
            if item >= self.max_items[-1]:
                self.max_items.append(item)
            return self.items.append(item)
        self.items.append(item)
        self.max_items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        if bool(self.items) and bool(self.max_items):
            if self.items[-1] == self.max_items[-1]:
                self.max_items.pop()
            return self.items.pop()
        return 'error'

    def get_max(self):
        if bool(self.items) and bool(self.max_items):
            return self.max_items[-1]
        return None
```

Comment: Вам для этой задачи надо иметь 2 стека. Один для всех значений, второй - только для максимумов.

Comment: Строго говоря, первый стек даже не нужен, только стек максимумов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy как тогда обслуживать pop операцию? Она не обязательно же удаляет максимум.

Comment: Вот пример двух стеков: `[4, -5, 7]`, `[4, 4, 7]`. Второй стек решает все задачи, первый просто изменяется но ни где не используется (операция `pop` не возвращает значение в этой задаче).

Comment: Мне Гугл по слову `StackMaxEffective` первой же ссылкой выдал вот это [решение](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracking-current-maximum-element-in-a-stack/) :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ха, в этом есть смысл.

Comment: так, ночью посидел, вроде сделал один вариант, но не знаю, верный он или нет, добавил код.

Comment: Я тоже добавил код в свой ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подскажу сперва идею. Сделайте стек в котором хранятся как значения, так и максимумы. Например:

```
команда  стек                          результат
pop      []                            error
pop      []                            error
push 4   [(4, 4)]
push -5  [(4, 4), (-5, 4)]
push 7   [(4, 4), (-5, 4), (7, 7)]
pop      [(4, 4), (-5, 4)]
pop      [(4, 4)]
get_max  [(4, 4)]                      4
pop      []
get_max  []                            None
```

Как записывать и использовать максимумы догадайтесь сами.

P.S. Пристально поглядев на условия можно понять, что первое значение из пары не используется. То есть вам достаточно хранить только максимумы в стеке. Вот так:

```
команда  стек         результат
pop      []           error
pop      []           error
push 4   [4]
push -5  [4, 4]
push 7   [4, 4, 7]
pop      [4, 4]
pop      [4]
get_max  [4]          4
pop      []
get_max  []           None
```

Стек избыточен в этой конкретной реализации: он хранит и значения и максимумы. Зато у него нормальный интерфейс:

```
class StackMaxEffective:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack_ = []

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.stack_)

    def push(self, item):
        if self.stack_:
            new_max = max(item, self.stack_[-1][1])
        else:
            new_max = item
        self.stack_.append((item, new_max))

    def pop(self):
        return self.stack_.pop()[0]

    def get_max(self):
        return self.stack_[-1][1]


s = StackMaxEffective()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    cmd = input().split()
    if cmd[0] == 'pop':
        if s:
            s.pop()
        else:
            print('error')
    if cmd[0] == 'push':
        s.push(int(cmd[1]))
    if cmd[0] == 'get_max':
        if s:
            print(s.get_max())
        else:
            print('None')
```